# Poor performance with Nvidia 540M and 352.63 drivers on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

After I installed the drivers and switched to the NVIDIA card the framerates I get on glmark2 are just absurd:

```
=======================================================
glmark2 2012.08
=======================================================
OpenGL Information
GL_VENDOR:     NVIDIA Corporation
GL_RENDERER:   GeForce GT 540M/PCIe/SSE2
GL_VERSION:    4.5.0 NVIDIA 352.63
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 421 FrameTime: 2.375 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 427 FrameTime: 2.342 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 443 FrameTime: 2.257 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 424 FrameTime: 2.358 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 449 FrameTime: 2.227 ms
[shading] shading=gouraud: FPS: 395 FrameTime: 2.532 ms
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf: FPS: 393 FrameTime: 2.545 ms
```

The same tests with the default drivers, using the Intel card, perform way better at about 2000FPS. I know that the NVIDIA card should pull about 4000FPS on this tests.

Is there something I'm missing here? Please help :)